# Not able to load @angular/platform-browser-dynamic

Tags: angular

When the application loads I am getting the following error.

```
http://localhost:49769/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:21 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:49769/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:49769/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:49769/app/main.js(anonymous function) @ localhost/:21
http://localhost:49769/node_modules/@angular/core/index.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Please find the folder structure of placing the config and .ts files in my project. Please validate whether the files are placed in correct folders[image]

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "Testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "repository": { }
}
```

systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'

    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },

        '@angular/common': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/compiler': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/core': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/http': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/platform-browser': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/router': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },

    };

    var packageNames = [
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/compiler',
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/forms',
      '@angular/http',
      '@angular/platform-browser',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
      '@angular/router'
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form 
    // '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Why the application is not able to load platform-browser-dynamic under node_modules? I verified the files exists under the specified folders, still I am getting this error.

Note: though the NPM/Dependencies folder is saying that "Not installed", but I can expand the folder and notice that all the references are installed properly, but still it displays this error/warning message

Comment: have you try to restart IDE ?

Comment: tried multiple times, no use...any other suggestions?

Comment: Try blowing away the entire node_modules dir and running `npm install` again.  If it still persists, file a bug report on the angular team's github page.  Your config file and package.json looks fine to me, so it's not obvious what's going on and hard to reproduce the issue without replicating your environment.

Comment: Check your systemjs config https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/systemjs.config.js#L43 Specifically notice `bundles` folder

Comment: tried blowing up entire node_modules, recreating from scratch from the Quickstart tutorials but not working. In plunker it works fine, same config settings and other components when placed in Visual studio IDE, on running the application I am getting this error. Please download zip file from the Github URL, https://github.com/snkrishnan1/Angular2RC4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not import the `node_modules` from `wwwroot`, but you have to copy the bundles in a destination folder in `wwwroot`, for example by gulp, and then import them from there by `systemjs.config.js`.
The `systemjs.config.js` position is correct in wwwroot.

I suggest you follow a few examples, like this: https://github.com/ajtowf/aspnetcore-angular2-seed